# How to Stream data with Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, streaming

I have a very large csv files. I want to stream the rows of data either "one by one" or "batch by batch" and put (WRITE_APPEND) it into BigQuery using AirFlow. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you tried to add [this kind of code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples) ?

Comment: @PowerCat cool! But I forget to mention there are IO processes before loading the data to BigQuery. That's why I want to use Airflow to schedule and apply concurrency for each IO Task

Comment: The file is not directly compliant with BigQuery?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere basically, i want to call an api with parameters based on some columns and then change other column according to the api result

Comment: I'm asking because it's far more efficient to load all the data in BigQuery, and then transform, clean, reorder them with a simple SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to have all the elements on your use case, but I propose you a solution.

From your `Airflow` DAG, you can sequence your tasks in the following way :

- Task 1 : load the `CSV` files to `BigQuery` staging tables via a `GCSToBigQuery` operator
- Task 2 : Add a `PythonOperator` containing your `API` call and store the result in another `BigQuery` staging table
- Task 3 : Use a `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` with a query. This query will join the info between the first and the second staging tables (the second is the result of your `API` call), apply some fields renaming and minimal transformations. Load the result in your final `BigQuery` table.